# Python SQLAlchemy in-memory database connect

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a in-memory database with python and I want to use SQLAlchemy with it.

All my application is currently working directly with queries to the db.

I've seen multiple ways of connecting but none of it is working. My current attempt stands as:

```
# Creates an sqlite database in memory
db = Database(filename=':memory:', schema='schema.sql')
db.recreate()

# ORM
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
User = Base.classes.user

session = Session(engine)
```

This gives `AttributeError: user`. How do I properly connect my database to the SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 2):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine   
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, Session
 
engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", echo=True, future=True)
session = Session(engine)
registry().metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: Although this code might be an answer to the question, it would be more helpful to future readers if an explanation was added.

Answer (score 1):

[ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) is your friend.

You can attach an in-memory database to the current database session.

E.g.,

```
db.init('sqlite://')
db.execute("ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS my_database")
db.create_all()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't figure out how to use your answer within my code

Comment: In order to use `:memory:` you need to specify an empty url for your db.
`db = create_engine('sqlite://')`.

Your code: `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')` is wrong.
[Look here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html)

Comment: @MarcoMilanesio, the syntax is wrong, the correct syntax for ATTACH is

`ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS my_database;`