Python - Unit tests - Sql Alchemy - Automap
I am trying to write unit tests for functions that execute Sql Alchemy queries. I am using Automap to create models automatically. As I have access to views and not tables, I have explicitly specified just the primary key of my model.Below is my code.
sql_alchemy_models.py
class Model1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_cust_data'

    CustID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


main.py
from some_path.sql_alchemy_models import Model1

def get_info(session, cust_id):
   cust_id = session.execute(select(Model1.CustID).filter(Model1.CustID == cust_id)).scalar()
   return cust_id


test_main.py
from mock_alchemy.mocking import UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock
from main import get_info

@pytest.fixture
def session():
    return UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock()


def test_info(session, mocker):
    mocker.patch('some_path.main.Model1')
    session.execute.return_value.scalar.return_value = 1
    result = get_info(session, 1)
    assert result == 1

When I run the above test, I get this error - sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got <MagicMock name='Model1.CustID' id='4483669544'>.
Can someone please share how to resolve this error ?
Test passes when I replace 1 with None :
def test_info(session):
    session.execute.return_value.scalar.return_value = None
    result = get_info(session, 1)
    assert result is None

Not sure why this happens.
I made it work like this :
def test_get_cust_id(session, mocker):
    mock = mocker.MagicMock()
    session.execute.return_value = mock
    mock.scalar.return_value = 2
    cust_id = get_cust_id(session)
    assert cust_id == 2


new_main.py
def get_expense_type_id(session, customer_id):
  name_exclude_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  exp_id = (session.execute(select(Model1.ExpID).                                          
  filter(Model1.CustID == customer_id,Model1.Type == "LineItem", 
  Model1.Name.notin_(name_exclude_list))).scalar())                             
         
 return exp_id 


test_new_main.py
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

# doubt : should i create this model ? In my original script, I 
# have used Automap to scan the database and automatically create 
# classes.

class Model1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_dummy'

    ExpID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    CustID = Column(Integer)
    Type = Column(String(30))
    Name = Column(String(30))

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def test_session():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:', 
    echo=True, future=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    return session

def test_get_expense_type_id(test_session):
with test_session as s:
    s.add_all([ExpenseReportItemType(CustomerID=1, 
    Type="LineItem", Name="Name1"),])
    s.commit()
    name_exclude_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    exp_id = (s.execute(select(ExpenseReportItemType.ExpenseReportItemTypeID).                       filter(ExpenseReportItemType.CustomerID == 1                              ExpenseReportItemType.Type == "LineItem",                              ExpenseReportItemType.Name.notin_(name_exclude_list))).
                       scalar())

    assert exp_id == 1


Why are you patching Model1? You should only patch session object.

@defalt When I remove the Model1 patch, I get this error - None != 1
Expected :1
Actual   :None

Don't mock the query; you might as well just mock the session and have session.execute return the the desired value while ignoring its argument. What you are really trying to test is the query itself, for which you want a proper database (so more like an integration test).

Thanks @chepner. I have posted my solution. Does it look correct to you ?

No; the problem with that is that you aren't really testing anything. The query could be anything, and the test will still pass. The "right" way to test this function is to let it query a database; the trick is being able to spin up a fast, simple database that session will query directly, no mocking involved.

(Mocking the query is wrong at the other end of the spectrum; it doesn't test that the function works, only that this particular implementation of the function works.)

Ideally, your test should pass/fail for all (or as many as possible) correct implementations of the function.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333314/python-sqlalchemy-in-memory-database-connect, for example. You won't mock anything, just create an in-memory database (and a corresponding session to pass to get_info) against which you can let get_info execute as intended.

Thank you @chepner. I will look at the link.

@chepner Based on your suggestion, I have tried a new approach. When you get a moment, can you please review new_main.py and test_new_main.py ? My main doubt is if I should create a new class even though in my new_main script , I am using a model that is automatically created using Automap.
